# Javascript to jQuery Get value of Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

After having successfully completed an application in Javascript, I am trying to make it more jQuery friendly.  However, when I try to get the value of a radio button like so:

```
 // relavent declarations: 

var radio = $("[name='buttons']");  // 4 radio buttons
var val = '';
var score = 0;


for( var q in radio ) {
if (radio[q].checked)
    val = radio[q].val();
}
     if(val === correct) {
    score++;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that the equivalent in straight Javascript is like this:

```
for( var q in radio ) {
if (radio[q].checked)
    val = radio[q].value;
}
     if(val === correct) {
    score++;
}
```

My Javascript console keeps giving me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'"  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('input:radio').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
     var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: @Nick D can u post html pls

Comment: HTML: <input type="radio" name="buttons" value="Shaft"><label name="labels" id="a"></label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="buttons" value="Elmo"><label name="labels" id="b"></label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="buttons" value="Fozzie"><label name="labels" id="c"></label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="buttons" value="Beaker"><label name="labels" id="d"></label>

Comment: Console error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'

Comment: @Nick D how you called that function

Comment: @NIck D you can get the radion button value using $('input:radio[name=buttons]:checked').val().You no need to loop then .Because they all having same name

Answer (score 1):

`radio[q]` will give you a raw DOM node object, you probably want the associated jQuery object, so try `radio[q].eq(q)`.

See: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
$(":radio:checked").each(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are writing some thing that have an answer and user if checked correct one then he will get a score

**Suggestion 1)** Give all the check box the same name , so that only one can be checked

```
 <input type="radio" name="Answer" />
```

**Suggestion 2)** get the selected checkbox value from myForm

```
 $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

As close as I think you want.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                var radio = $("input[type='radio']");
                for (var i in radio) {
                    i = parseInt(i);
                    var r = radio[i];
                    if ($(r).prop("checked") == true) {

                        console.log($(r).val());
                    }
                }

            })
 })
```

Added the readout of the value